# Cannot find report invalid id error while calling Oracle Reports using Oracle Forms 

Tags: forms, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

When I call report using Oracle forms following error get display

> FRM-41219 : Cannot find report invalid id

```
DECLARE 
rept REPORT_OBJECT; 
v_rep VARCHAR2(100); 
rep_status varchar2(200); 
BEGIN 

rept := find_report_object('EMP.RDF'); 

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept ,REPORT_SERVER , 'repsrv'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESFORMAT,' HTML');


v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(rept); 
rep_status:=REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(v_rep); 

WHILE rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED') 
LOOP 
rep_status := report_object_status(v_rep); 
END LOOP; 
IF rep_status='FINISHED' THEN 
message('REPORT WAS CORRECTLY RUN'); 
ELSE 
message('REPORT FAILED WITH STATUS: '||rep_status); 
END IF;  
END;
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_report_object` expects a report ID, not the file name for the report RDF. The report ID will be the name of the report object you create in the form.

Comment: jeffrey know the problem is i am able to run the report successfully but i am not able to create pdf file . plss help me out

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question. Remember, they're free, and you're more likely to get good assistance from more people :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: can u explain more? I didn't understand your second sentence. :(